# autocomplete results to fancybox

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, fancybox

I'm using jQuery autocomplete to produce links to various pages. Clicking those links should open in fancybox. Since the links aren't created on page load `$(".iframeFancybox1").fancybox();` is not working (works fine for all other elements using this class). The question is: How can I hook to autocomplete's ready-state to fire up .fancybox() again and make these links open in fancybox?

JS:

```
var items = [];
$(".forms .menu-item a").each(function(n){
    items.push({
        label: $(this).html(),
        url: $(this).attr('href')
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    var availableTags = items;
    jQuery( ".custom-search .text" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        appendTo: ".ac-result"
    }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    var listItem = $("<li></li>")
    .data("ui-autocomplete-item", item)
    .append("<a class='iframeFancybox1 cat1' href='"+ item.url +"'>"+ item.label +"</a>")
    .appendTo(ul);

    return listItem;
    };

});
```

I have tried using .keyup() on the input-field to init fancybox with no luck, problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try binding it to the ul at the end of your document ready:

```
$('ul.ulSelector').on('click', 'a', function() {
    $(this).fancybox();
});
```

if this doesn't work then you can try this in you `_renderItem` function:

```
var listItem = $("<li></li>")
.data("ui-autocomplete-item", item)
.appendTo(ul);

var link = $("<a class='iframeFancybox1 cat1' href='"+ item.url +"'>"+ item.label +"</a>");

listItem.append(link);
link.fancybox();
```

Comment: Didn't try the first one since the ul is also created via autocomplete (might still work). Nevertheless second one worked perfect. Thank you!